# Auto Arranging data in group wise with serial Number in existing table

Tags: mysql

I have an existing table (Table A) which I want to be arranged in group wise per subject column and id to be arranged in ID column as per Table -B. And in future if i add any data it should also arranged in the same manner. Is it possible in Mysql? i tried to arrange the column bgroup wise but i am not able to generate the id

[image]

Comment: Your external table link appears to be broken.  Please include all relevant data directly in the question.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen MY table is there but it canot be visible because of my reputation.I am new to this forum

Comment: @octobus It is only to search the data .Can you help me please

Comment: Can anyone help me in this.Viewed 16 times still no answer